# Render Visual to vector based graphic

Tags: c#, wpf, graphics

I have some problems printing WPF `UserControls`. The UserControl I'm creating is for now rendered as a bitmap and passed through an interface to some 3rd party libraries for printing. Rendering to a bitmap will result in poor quality of the print when the user zooms in for example.

I read about vector graphics on msdn and read about how WPF uses these technologies in `Path` objects for exmple, but I could not find a way to somehow render a `UserControl` or just a `Visual` to some vector based graphic instead of a bitmap.

Can anyone help? Thanks

Comment: You can't simply use built-in printing support provided by [PrintDialog.PrintVisual](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.printdialog.printvisual.aspx)?

Comment: @Clemens I can't. As I wrote above the printing part will happen somewhere else. I need to pass the content and for now I'm passing a bitmap, but rather I would pass something like a vector graphic for quality reasons.